# Change two-dimentional array's certain index value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to put certain value in certain two dimensional array but it appends different.

Here is my code.

```js
const arr = []
const tdArr = []

arr.length = 5
arr.fill('p', 0)

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  tdArr.push(arr)
}

const makeRnd = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min)
  max = Math.floor(max)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
}

let firstRnd = makeRnd(0, 4)
let secRnd = makeRnd(0, 4)
let tdArr2 = [...tdArr]
tdArr2[firstRnd][secRnd] = 'q'

console.log(tdArr2)
```

I don't know why not (for example) `tdArr2[0][1]` is not changed but also change all second value of arrays.

It seems easy one but cannot google it :(
Thanks for help!

Comment: You're filling the array with a reference to the same array.

Comment: Create the nested arrays inside the `for` loop, not once before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tdArr.push([...arr])` in the for loop instead of `tdArr.push(arr)`.

```js
const arr = []
const tdArr = []

arr.length = 5
arr.fill('p', 0)

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  tdArr.push([...arr])
}

const makeRnd = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min)
  max = Math.floor(max)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
}

let firstRnd = makeRnd(0, 4)
let secRnd = makeRnd(0, 4)
let tdArr2 = [...tdArr]
tdArr2[firstRnd][secRnd] = 'q'

console.log(tdArr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Dave Newton every element of `tdArr` array is the same one which is a reference to `arr` so when you change a value of `arr` all elements of `tdArr` are changes as they all reference the same array.

I would push an array literal instead of creating an array and then push it or create a copy like mentioned in the answer above and push the copy on each iteration.

```
tdArr.push(['p']);
```